# removing consecutive duplicates in strings R

Tags: regex, r, string, text, data-cleaning

I'd like to collapse two strings `s1 = "word1 word2 word3"` and `s2 = "word2 word3 word4"` but removing the extra (future) consecutive overlap/duplicate (`"word2 word3"`). That is, I should obtain `s = "word1 word2 word3 word4`" rather than `s = "word1 word2 word3 word2 word3 word4"`.

More simply, it should also work for single-word overlaps: `s1 = "word1 word2"` and `s2 = "word2 word3"` should give me `s = word1 word2 word3"` rather than `s = "word1 word2 word2 word3"`.

I am using `wordnumber` for illustration purposes but of course it should work for any word...

Comment: I would go with paste(unique(strsplit(paste(s1, s2, " "), " ")), " ")

Comment: Yes, I only want to remove **consecutive** duplicates

Comment: I must admit I feel like I'm missing something here. This is just a `union` operation in each example you give.  `union(strsplit(s1," ")[[1]], strsplit(s2," ")[[1]])` gives the expected result in both cases. If you have an example that doesn't work for this circumstance, you should show it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was surprisingly difficult, but I believe I have a solution:

```
sjoin <- function(s1,s2) {
    ss1 <- strsplit(s1,'\\s+')[[1L]];
    ss2 <- strsplit(s2,'\\s+')[[1L]];
    if (length(ss1)==0L) return(s2);
    if (length(ss2)==0L) return(s1);
    n <- 0L; for (i in seq(min(length(ss1),length(ss2)),1L))
        if (all(ss1[seq(to=length(ss1),len=i)]==ss2[seq(1L,len=i)])) {
            n <- i;
            break;
        }; ## end if
    paste(collapse=' ',c(ss1,if (n==0L) ss2 else ss2[-1:-n]));
}; ## end sjoin()
sjoin('1 2 3','2 3 4');
## [1] "1 2 3 4"
sjoin('1 2 3 x','2 3 4');
## [1] "1 2 3 x 2 3 4"
sjoin('1 2 3','x 2 3 4');
## [1] "1 2 3 x 2 3 4"
sjoin('','')
## [1] ""
sjoin('a','');
## [1] "a"
sjoin('','a');
## [1] "a"
sjoin('a','a')
## [1] "a"
sjoin('a b c','a b c');
## [1] "a b c"
sjoin('a b c','c');
## [1] "a b c"
sjoin('a b c','c d');
## [1] "a b c d"
sjoin('b','b c d');
## [1] "b c d"
sjoin('a b','b c d');
## [1] "a b c d"
```

Comment: thank you very much. I have to go now but as soon as I have tested it later today I will accept your answer (it it indeed works - but I don't doubt it)

Comment: I finally found the time to test it. Very nice work, it does the job perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Use `unique` on the result, that should remove all the duplicates.
 And perhaps also use `sort`?

---

EDIT: Sorry, my first answer did miss the point completely.  Here's a revised solution based on the `stringr`-package, that I think should work.  The idea is to first split the strings into vectors, then compare the vectors and check if an overlap is present - finally join the vectors based on whether or not an overlap was detected.

```
s1 = "word1 word2  word3"
s2 = "word2 word3 word4"

library(stringr)
.s1_splitted <- str_split(
    string = s1,
    pattern = "\ +")[[1]]
.s2_splitted <- str_split(
    string = s2,
    pattern = "\ +")[[1]]


.matches12 <- charmatch(
    x = .s1_splitted,
    table = .s2_splitted)
```

If the last number is different from `NA`, and shorter than the
length of `.s1_splitted`, then check if the end of the vector
looks like it ought to do.

```
.last_element <- tail(.matches12, n = 1)
if (! is.na(.last_element)) {
    if (.last_element <= length(.s1_splitted)) {
        .overlap <- identical(
            x = 1:.last_element,
            y = tail(x = .matches12,
                     n = .last_element))
    }
} else
    .overlap <- FALSE
```

Join the components, based on overlap.

```
if (.overlap) {
    .joined <- c(
        head(x = .s1_splitted,
             n = - .last_element),
        .s2_splitted)
} else
    .joined <- c(.s1_splitted,
                  .s2_splitted)
```

Convert back to a string

```
.result <- paste(.joined, collapse = " ")
```